# Failed system update

Tags: updates, repository

While doing a software update I received an error. Trouble shooting the issue I received this information:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noskcaj/indicator-gtk3/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Is there a problem with the repository?  Or should I just comment out that repository?

Answer (score 0):

This repository does not exist anymore. You should delete it.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:noskcaj/indicator-gtk3
```

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news!*

Comment: @DouglasStowell Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the repository, as has been posted in the previous answer, you just need to use the key, --fix-missing in your command to avoid problems happening and finding alternatives of the repository you are connecting to as follows:

sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

Which will do the trick.